# Microsoft Edge cannot print PDF using javascript print()

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing, microsoft-edge

I am using Microsoft Edge 41.16299.402.0 .

I would like to use iframe to embed the PDF blob and using contentWindow.print() to    show the printer dialog directly.

Everything work fine in other browsers but don't work in Microsoft Edge.

The error message shown "Error: Unexpected call to method or property access."

Anyone know how to solve this?

Below is my code:

```
    let loading = document.createElement("div");
    loading.id = "printLoading";
    loading.style.cssText = 'position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 999;background: rgba(6,6,6,0.3);top: 0;left: 0;';
    document.body.appendChild(loading);


    var iframe = document.getElementById("printIframe");
    if (iframe != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.id = 'printIframe';
    iframe.style.display = 'none';

    console.log("pdfBlob", pdfBlob)
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
    let timeOut = 0;
    var inter = window.setInterval(function () {
        try {
            if (iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
                document.getElementById("printIframe").contentWindow.print();
                window.clearInterval(inter);
                let loading = document.getElementById("printLoading");
                if (loading != null) {
                    document.body.removeChild(loading);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            timeOut += 100;
            if(timeOut>5000){
                window.clearInterval(inter);
                let loading = document.getElementById("printLoading");
                if (loading != null) {
                    document.body.removeChild(loading);
                }
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
```

Comment: I'd like to know what does pdfBlob refer to? I could not reproduce your issue since there is error:pdfBlob is not defined.Have you used some references?

Comment: Finally I find that this is a issue in MS EdgeHTML 16